# Переделать функцию

Tags: javascript

```
    addEventListener("click", function () {
  const labels = [...document.querySelectorAll('[name="emails"]:checked + label')];
  document.getElementById("emails").innerText = labels.map(label => label.innerText).join(', ');;
});
```

Как переделать, что бы не использовать "=>"

Comment: `function (label) {return label.innerText}`

Comment: От многоточия тоже скорее всего придётся избавиться)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы же сами частично уже использовали - в `addEventListener` использовали вызов функции, хотя могли бы сделать и `=>`

```
addEventListener("click", function () {
    const labels = [...document.querySelectorAll('[name="emails"]:checked + label')];
    document.getElementById("emails").innerText = labels.map(function(label) {
        return label.innerText
    }).join(', ');
});
```